What is the rationale for the expression class{}.refmem to be an lvalue expression
I came to know that S{}.rval is an lvalue expression. I want to know the rationale behind considering it an lvalue expression.
Why are access to non-static member of reference type lvalue, even when the object is an rvalue?
struct S {
    int val;
    int& rval = val;
};
int main() {
    S{}.val; // xvalue
    S{}.rval; // lvalue
}

My expectation would have been that a reference to a "soon to die entity" would also be "soon to die".
So I'd like to understand the rationale of the rule(s).

The compiler can't know whether rval is soon to die.

Change int& rval = val; to int& rval = some_global;.  Has the type changed?

For the same reason a function call to a function returning an lvlaue ref is an lvlaue expression. Like in int i = 0; int& f(){return i;} the call f(); is lvalue expression.

"I want to know the rationale behind considering it an lvalue expression" - why not?  It has a name, and a value can be assigned to it. Hence it's an lvalue. Regardless of its lifetime.

@RemyLebeau I think it's the over way around: it can be assigned because it's a lvalue (the built-in assignment operators expect that the left operand is an lvalue). Regards


My expectation would have been that a reference to a "soon to die entity" would also be "soon to die".

That is not always true. The reference member may alias an object that will outlive the temporary S{}.
For example:
int i = 10;
struct S {
   
    int& rval = i; // rval refers to the global i
};
int main() {
    S{}.rval;     //the aliased object will outlive the object expression `S{}`
}

